# How to allow user call stored procedure in Postgresql without granting additional rights?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, transactions

I have a stored procedure in Postgresql that contains COMMIT statement and I would like users to only access this procedure without giving them right to select, insert, etc. In function I would use SECURITY DEFINER, but from official docs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createprocedure.html:

> A SECURITY DEFINER procedure cannot execute transaction control statements (for example, COMMIT and ROLLBACK, depending on the language).

As I understand this means that I can not use SECURITY DEFINER and have to grant user any right that is needed in stored procedure to allow user to execute it which completely defeats the whole purpose of allowing users only functions or procedures.

How does one call stored procedure with COMMIT statement in it without having individual grants to all statements inside the procedure?

Answer (score 6):

You can grant privileges to a specific procedure so that the user can have transaction control privileges for that procedure only.

```
GRANT ALL ON PROCEDURE <procedure_name> TO <role>;
```

Comment: @J Spratt, Thank you for answer, but it still  throws error :"ERROR:  permission denied for table projects"

Comment: @niks I haven't tried before but you may be able to `GRANT` and `REVOKE` privileges to `CURRENT_USER` from within the stored procedure. That way the user only has privileges for the scope of the stored procedure.

Comment: @J Spratt Haven't succeeded yet. Any tips on how to to accomplish this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `CREATE PROCEDURE` is only available in postgres 11 which I don't have on my machine right now and dbfiddle doesn't allow the creation of users. From the documentation you quoted, it says 'depending on language'. Have you tried using `LANGUAGE PLPGSQL` with `SECURITY DEFINER` in your procedure definition? Why is using a `FUNCTION` out of the question or why are `COMMIT` statements a necessity?

Comment: @J Spratt Sorry for so late reply. I have found out that it is kind of a limitation of a procedure at the moment. I also found out that everything you put in function is internally wrapped inside transaction and at the end it is "all or nothing" anyway, which is the reason why I wanted to use procedure so that I could commit the changes at the end. Therefore I will go with the function! Thank you for your helpful ideas!

Answer (score 3):

There is a workaround for this limitation.

> A SECURITY DEFINER procedure cannot execute transaction control
> statements (for example, COMMIT and ROLLBACK, depending on the
> language).

It is possible to call (SELECT or PERFORM) function with SECURITY DEFINER from stored procedure. Of course the user must have a GRANT EXECUTE on both the procedure and the function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure_test()
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
begin

    PERFORM function_test();
    COMMIT;
    PERFORM function_test();

end
$$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_test(
) RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER
AS $$
begin

    -- some code

end
$$;
```

Comment: Keep in mind functions act as a transaction themselves. Functions either commit immediately after successful execution or rollback if something within the body failed. This is also to say `PERFORM some_function(); COMMIT;` is redundant. Like saying write it, then write nothing. Also, nested functions act as their own transactions so you can exploit commit/rollback control through that.